# SSM document does not use role to modify volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, aws-ssm

I am trying to modify an existing volume on an EC2 instance using SSM. I attached a role with a policy that allows to modify volumes on EC2 instances. The permission I picked in the policy is called ModifyVolume. When I try to run my script it gives me the following message:

> An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the ModifyVolume operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.

I am sure that the policy I use grants me this permission so I wonder why it does not work?

This is my SSM document:

```
---
schemaVersion: "2.2"
assumeRole: "{{AutomationAssumeRole}}"
description: "Resizes the specified EBS volume to the target size"
parameters:
  AutomationAssumeRole:
    type: "String"
    description: "The ARN of the role that allows Automation to perform the actions on your behalf."
    default: "arn:aws:iam::accountnumber:role/SSMUpdateVolume"
  VolumeId:
    type: "String"
    description: "(Required) EBS volume ID"
  Size:
    type: "String"
    description: "(Required) Target size for the selected volume in GB"
mainSteps:
- action: "aws:runShellScript"
  name: "ModifyVolumeSize"
  inputs:
    runCommand:
    - "export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1"
    - "aws ec2 modify-volume --size {{Size}} --volume-id {{VolumeId}}"
```

This is the role I need below:
[image]

I noticed that it works when I assign the permission directly to the role which is assigned to the instance itself. However, I want to only allow this permission temporarily when I use the SSM document. So this means the SSM document does not apply this permission, but uses the one on the instance itself where this ModifyVolume permission is missing. How can I fix this?

I assume that this might be because I am using the aws:runShellScript command, so that it does not apply the role at all and simply calls the scripts on the instance? Could that be the reason? And if that is the case what do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but you have a mis-matched number of curly braces in: `assumeRole: "{{AutomationAssumeRole}"`

Comment: Yes that was a typo, it did not change anything unfortunately

Comment: Can you please add the policy to your Question so we can try to reproduce?

Comment: I added the policy and added some additional information on my case

Comment: I was about to try and reproduce your situation but then I noticed that `assumeRole` is referring to a parameter. It might be possible that this won't work, since parameters are defined separately. Can you try hard-coding the ARN of the IAM Role in `assumeRole` (eg `assumeRole: arn:aws:iam::accountnumber:role/SSMUpdateVolume` and see whether that works?

Comment: I have tried adding the parameter directly to assumeRole, the result remains the same. 
If you could try to reproduce it and tell me what you think that might help

Comment: @Benny that appears to be a policy in the screenshot not a role, are you able to go through https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-permissions.html and check that you have a service role configured like these instructions?

Comment: @Benny that appears to be a policy in the screenshot not a role, are you able to go through https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-permissions.html and check that you have a service role configured like these instructions?

Comment: Ah! @Benny -- I was assuming that you create an IAM Role called `arn:aws:iam::accountnumber:role/SSMUpdateVolume` and assigned the `Modify Volume` permissions to that role. Is that correct?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes thats correct the role is called SSMUpdateVolume and it is assigned a policy that has the ModifyVolume permission in SSM, as said this does not work. Instead the SSM document uses the role of the instance itself.

Comment: I'll try and reproduce this in a test environment. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: I got to reproduce the error. Not sure why it happens, though. I'll keep trying.

Comment: I think I understand the issue. Will try to put it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me some time to wrap my head around this question, but I think I've got an answer:

AWS Systems Manager Documents work in the following way:

They have **actions** (e.g. `aws:runShellScript`, `aws:createStack`, etc.)

These actions use either the default **SSM service role**, or a role injected via `assumeRole`.

That means in your example the **action** `aws:runShellScript` is executed using the **role** `SSMUpdateVolume`.

However, the the individual commands in the shell script are run using local permissions on the EC2 instance, i.e. the role attached to the Instance Profile, which doesn't have the required permissions.

So, it makes sense that this doesn't work.

**To achieve what you want**, you could--instead of executing the shell commands--use the [`aws:executeAwsApi`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-action-executeAwsApi.html) action to modify the volume.

Please note: You are using a document of type Command. For this to work, you need to create a document of type [Automation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-documents.html). To do this, when in the AWS Systems Manager Documents console, please choose **Create automation** instead of **Create command or session**.

The final document could look similar to the following:

```
description: Resizes the specified EBS volume to the target size
schemaVersion: '0.3'
assumeRole: '{{ AutomationAssumeRole }}'
parameters:
  AutomationAssumeRole:
    type: String
    default: 'arn:aws:iam::accountnumber:role/SSMUpdateVolume'
    description: The ARN of the role that allows Automation to perform the actions on your behalf.
  VolumeId:
    type: String
    description: (Required) EBS volume ID
  Size:
    type: String
    description: (Required) Target size for the selected volume in GB
mainSteps:
  - name: ModifyVolumeSize
    action: 'aws:executeAwsApi'
    inputs:
      Service: ec2
      Api: ModifyVolume
      Size: '{{ Size }}'
      VolumeId: '{{ VolumeId }}'
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to use this code:
InvalidDocumentContent: Unknown plugin name: aws:executeAwsApi

Comment: Yes, you're right. `aws:executeAwsApi` is used in a different schema. Having that said, my original answer made it much more complicated than it needed to be. With an AWS SSSM Automation Dcoument, you can directly invoke the `ec2:ModifyVolume` API. You don't need to run a script in the EC2 instance. I'm going to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Done. I hope this helps now. Please note, that you must create a different type of SSM Document. When in the AWS Systems Manager Documents console, please choose **Create automation** instead of **Create command or session**.

Comment: Mhhh, well I preferred the previous solution together with a working aws:executeAwsApi command .... background to this is that I was planning to perform some script operations which I assume are not available through using SSM document alone ... I know I have not mentioned it in here, but this was my plan originally ..., I will I update my answer with the additional things I need so it is clear why it would be more beneficial to me to use script commands here

Comment: Please, if you have a different question now, consider accepting this and writing a new one. We have spent a lot of time trying to help you, based on your original question and at least I would appreciate this not to be too much of a moving target.

Comment: Having that said, with the AWS SSM Automation Document you can also execute python or PowerShell scripts using the `aws:executeScript` module.

Comment: Alright, I will mark this as accepted answer as it is solving the issue and will try to resolve the rest myself with aws:executeScript, thanks a lot